В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида при сохранении изображения
У меня возникает проблема при сохранении изображения при повторном вызове метода для обработки и сохранения изображения. Возникает только во второй раз, в первом случае все успешно сохраняется. Вроде даже обернул все в using, но почему то все равно нет доступа к изображению. Причем нужно именно перезаписать файл, а не сделать копию
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(450, 450))
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    graphics.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);

    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, 100, 0, 100, 400);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 200, 50, 100, 100);
    }

    bmp.Save(_imageViewModel.ImageSource);
}
}

Пробовал так же работать с изображением через отдельный FileStream, все равно возникала та же проблема

Частично помог принудительный вызов GarbageCollector, но с учетом того, что повторный вызов метода происходит минимум через пол минуты

_imageViewModel.ImageSource - этот путь ещё где-то используется? Например, если оттуда читается Bitmap, то он может держать хендл.

Дёргать GC не разобравшись в проблеме - так себе история. Гарантии, что GC по команде что-то сразу же очистит, нет.

Подозреваю, что сохранить надо после уничтожения Graphics
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(450, 450))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graphics.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);

        // ... рисование
    }
    bmp.Save(_imageViewModel.ImageSource);
}

Возможно при открытом Graphics где-то подвисают ресурсы.
using дожен обеспечивать 100% очистку ресурсов немедленно. Если это не происходит, значит где-то ресурсы придерживаете. Возможно за пределами показанного кода. Вы точно нигде в другом месте не читаете из этого файла?
Если читаете, то это надо делать как-то так
Bitmap bmp;
using (var buffer = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(_imageViewModel.ImageSource))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(buffer);
}

В этом случае при чтении Bitmap сразу же отпустит файл.
Альтернативно можно сохранять через буфер.
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(450, 450))
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graphics.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);

        // ... рисование
    }
    bmp.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (var fs = File.Create(_imageViewModel.ImageSource))
    {
        ms.CopyTo(fs);
    }
}

Тогда GDI+ ничего не узнает о файле и не захватит его. Но мне кажется, это лишнее, using должен сработать гарантированно.

Спасибо большое, помогло создание Bitmap через буфер. По идее, это изображение должно было отдельно после сохранения выводиться на экран через биндинг, но видимо я что то намудрил и туда bitmap подгружался
